# Varnish - redirect a request to another website/webserver

Tags: redirect, varnish, varnish-vcl

When you type in https://website.com/site I want the user to be redirected to http://ip:port because "/site" is in the url.

```
if (req.url  ~ "/site.*$"){

   set url = regsub(req.url, "site", "");
   set req.http.host = "ip:port";
   return (pass)

}
```

Comment: `redirected` as in returning 301,302,307,308 HTTP response to client or proxy client's request to this `ip:port`?

Comment: Yes. currently, when I type http://ip:port into the browser the website pops up just fine. So I want my varnish proxy to be able to redirect or rewrite the url to http://ip:port when  https://website.com/site is typed into the browser. "website" being varnish

Answer (score 0):

See https://www.varnish-software.com/developers/tutorials/redirect/ for a tutorial on how to perform HTTP redirections in Varnish.

Here's the relevant VCL example for you:

```
vcl 4.1;

backend default {
    .host = "127.0.0.1";
    .port = 8080;
}

sub vcl_recv {
    if(req.url == "/external") {
        return(synth(301,"https://external.example.com/"));
    }
}

sub vcl_synth {
    if (resp.status == 301) {
        set resp.http.location = resp.reason;
        set resp.reason = "Moved";
        return (deliver);
    }
}
```

Please change the URL matching logic and updated the redirection endpoint accordingly.